# Loopback Strongloop get ModelName from model instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, loopback

Using loopback I need to get the modelName from a model instance. Any Ideas?

```js
var myAccount = new app.models.Account({name: 'ACME'});
var modelName = myAccount.modelName;`
//should get 'Account'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to retrieve the model name by using (where this is the model):

```
this.definition.name;
```

Answer (score 4):

the correct answer is `instance.constructor.definition.name`, so in your case `myAccount.constructor.definition.name`